# Property 'projectNodes' does not exist on type 'Renderer2'

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am migrating my Angular project from Angular 4 to Angular 8. Currently I am updating Renderer to Renderer2. I have a code snippet

```
this._renderer.projectNodes(document.body, [this._element.nativeElement, this.backdrop.instance.element.nativeElement]);
```

I am trying to find what projectNodes method actually does to the DOM but I'm not able to find much detail about this method. Can someone please give details what projectNodes does and how to upgrade this code to Renderer2?

Answer (score 0):

As I correctly understand, this function just append child into your element (body), you can look here 
https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/hey-the-projectnodes-function-takes-the-parent-and-list-of-dom-elements-to-append-to-this-parent-e9d122b4d681

and here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/37a1078/nativescript-angular/renderer.ts#L196

so I think you can replace your code with two lines of `Renderer2.appendChild`